# Oracle OCCI not able to retrieve the values after decimal point properly

Tags: oracle, occi

I am retrieving the data from OracleDB using occi in my application.
While retrieving it, I found that the digits after decimal points were not properly retrieved.

For example, in the DB the original value was 12345.12 but while retrieving from resultset the value i got was 12345.1.

I need to retrieve the whole value (preferably double helps me a lot for my application mapping purpose). Any suggestions will help me a lot.

column in the Oracle DB is NUMBER(11,2) datatype.

I tried to retrieve from result set in the following ways but still got the same truncated value in it.

1. resultSet -> getDouble(1);
2. Number nr = resultSet -> getNumber(1);
   double d = nr.operator double();

Comment: any quick suggestions on this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried resultSet->getString(1) and able to get the whole value. Yes i need to cast it to double but getting the data is important than casting. So i will go for it. If anyone has any better solution post it and I am ready to take it.